# Export file and create two headers based on one column

Tags: r, csv, header

I'm not even sure how to approach this situation, I'm probably blocked. I have a wide dataframe, something like this

```
Date   Amy_X  Amy_Y  John_X  John_Y
March   14     15     10.5    14.5
April   10     11     15       16
```

I would like to export the data to a csv file with the following format

```
Date   Amy          John
        X     Y     X      Y
March   14    15    10.5   14.5
April   10    11    15     16
```

My first question is what is the best approach to achieve this. Should I separate `Amy_X` into `Amy`and `X`and then create a repeat of the vector of names `Amy, Amy, John, John` and use than as another header. What's the best solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question says to output the file to csv but the output shown is not comma-separated values (csv). We show both.

Using input data frame `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end, create a data frame from the headers and use separate_rows on it and rbind that to `DF`.  Then do any remaining fix ups.  Write it out without the row and column names and without quotes.  Replace `stdout()` with your file name.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF2 <- DF %>%
  names %>%
  as.list %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  separate_rows(everything()) %>%
  setNames(names(DF)) %>%
  rbind(DF)

DF2[2, 1] <- DF2[1, duplicated(unlist(DF2[1, ]))] <- ""

output <- capture.output(prmatrix(DF2, quote = FALSE,
  rowlab = rep("", nrow(DF2)), collab = rep("", ncol(DF2))))[-1]
writeLines(output, stdout())
```

giving the following which reproduces the output shown in the question:

```
Date  Amy       John     
      X    Y    X    Y   
March 14   15   10.5 14.5
April 10   11   15   16
```

If you really did want csv then use this instead of the `writeLines` and statement prior to it above:

```
write.table(DF2, stdout(), sep = ",", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, 
  col.names = FALSE)
```

giving:

```
Date,Amy,,John,
,X,Y,X,Y
March,14,15,10.5,14.5
April,10,11,15,16
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Date   Amy_X  Amy_Y  John_X  John_Y
March   14     15     10.5    14.5
April   10     11     15       16"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, yes, the output is `CSV` though I represented the desired output and not the `CSV` file. Thank you for your answer. A few points about your code: I cannot have long strings, otherwise, it doesn't work, but that's an easy fix. I have the date format in the column date, and your code converts the date into a numeric field. Saving the output to a `CSV` I don't get the columns separated, but maybe if I export with space as a separator that should work. Thank you!

Comment: Convert `Date` class columns to character first to prevent them from being converted to numeric.  The other comments are not clear to me but presumably you can deal with differences between what you have and what was shown in the question.